# Seamless images from photos using imagemagick

Tags: image, perl, imagemagick, batch-processing, imagemagick-convert

I have to create seamless square pictures from photos.
Each photo has the resolution 6000x4000 and converted image should have 4000x4000px or so. I would like to run this on Linux machine using imagemagick, from either a bash, or a perl script. Does anybody a simple way of doing it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is a seamless square picture? Do you want to crop one 6000x4000 image into a single 4000x4000 image by cutting off 2000 pixels? Or resize and distort the original picture? Or take 16 images of 6000x4000 and resize each one to 1000x1000 and montage them to make a single big 4000x4000? It its very unclear - to me at least!

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. I would like to crop single 6000x4000 image to 4000x4000 and make this image seamless. Cropping could be done in a way that 1000 pixels is cut from both sides.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with this image which is 600x400:

[image]

Now, if you want the central 400 pixels of the width and the full height of the original:

```
convert start.png -gravity center -extent 400x result.png
```

[image]

Or, if you want the rightmost 300 pixels:

```
convert start.png -gravity east -extent 300x result.png
```

[image]

Or, if, like your question but scaled down  by a factor of 10 , you want to start 100px in from the left and take 400px, you can crop with an offset:

```
convert start.png -crop 400x+100 result.png
```

[image]

**Note:**

I made the start image with:

```
convert xc:cyan xc:magenta xc:yellow +append -resize 600x400\! start.png
```

Comment: +1 for sharing the way you've created the whole picture. Now, is there a method to convert it to seamless picture?

Comment: @piotao The thing is, I don't know what you mean by *"seamless"*. I asked as a comment on 16th November under your question but I still don't know what you mean. A seam is a join or joint normally, so seamless means *"without"* joins and, as far as I can see, there are no join in my resulting image. If you explain what you mean, I will look again.

Comment: Seamless pictures are used in computer graphics for texturing 3d models. Such a picture is prepared in a way that you can tile it on any surface and you are not able to see the boundaries of the picture. Thus, it's name: seamless. Now, I have lot's of good photos of rocks, terrain, beddings, etc. and I would like to run automatic script for making them seamless at once. Some of them can be bad, but still some of them could be OK.

Comment: @piotao Are you talking about tessellations? If so, there are triangles, squares, hexagon and all sorts http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/tess/grids.htm Please give a proper example of what you mean.

Comment: One approach is described here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-Images-seamless-horizontally-or-vertically-/?ALLSTEPS
This has nothing to do with tesselation. This is only about creating a picture which has pixels on each side matching to pixels on the opposite side. I can do this in GIMP using mouse and menu Filters, but the idea is to convert all stuff automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Perl here. This will crop an image to 400x400 starting from position 0, 0 (top-left corner):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Image::Magick;

my $img = Image::Magick->new;

$img->Read('img.jpg');

print $img->Get('width') . " ";
print $img->Get('height') ."\n";

$img->Crop(geometry => '400x400+0+0');
$img->Write('img_new.jpg');

$img->Read('img_new.jpg');

print $img->Get('width') . " ";
print $img->Get('height') ."\n";
```

Output:

```
4128 2322 # original
400 400   # new
```

Comment: This seems to be right solution for me, thanks!!! Dunno who gave you -1, I'm giving +1 because this is the OK method for me. I'll check if that works.

Comment: @piotao since this is the only answer on an older post, and it works for you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. You should do this for any question you ask; always accept the best answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, this is only a part of the solution. Just a nice way of cropping images, but they are just cropped.
Another part of my question still is unsolved - how to convert them, after cropping, to seamless images? Seamless in a way that allow me to use them as a texture on big objects and not see any seams. Repeating pattern optimally shouldn't be too visible (I know, this depends on an image).

Comment: @piotao I did not realize exactly what you were trying to achieve, but I do now. Honestly, I don't know (or have the time to research) how to do that.